# Rails 3.2 force prepared statements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, prepared-statement

If i use expression `Model.find(1)` then rails executes it as prepared statement: `SELECT "models".* FROM "models" WHERE "models"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]`

But when I use `Model.where("id = ?", 1)` it executes without prepared statement: `SELECT "models".* FROM "models" WHERE (id = 1)`

How to force rails to use prepared statement in this case too?

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure you can.

But

```
Model.where(:id => 1)
```

Should generate a prepared statement. Fragment string works differently, so you can generate exactly what you need, in custom cases.

Edit :

Try this, i'm not sure it works, i can' test for now, but it looks like what you need :

```
 Client.where("created_at >= :start_date AND created_at <= :end_date",
   {:start_date => params[:start_date], :end_date => params[:end_date]})
```

More here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#conditions

In the placeholder section. Moreover date range works in the array format :

:date => date_begenning..date_end

Edit 2 : indeed you can, but i seems where don't support building this by hand.

You might build your prepared queries by hand :

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements.html#method-i-exec_query

```
exec_query(sql, name = 'SQL', binds = [])
```

There is also a bind method on your relation.

But both binds need that the value have a name method, they will crash if you give a fixnum, a hash, ect. I hadn't found any doc explaining how this works.

Bu for the where clause, as long it is of Class String, active ecord apply a .to_sql on it, so you don't get your prepared statement.

Comment: this was a simplified example, it real query i can't use hash. and i really need to run it as prepared query

Comment: Can you post the part of your query where you are struggling ?

Comment: there is a complex where with ORs ANDs and special operators like "period" && ?::daterange

Comment: I have edited my post, with something that looks like what you need.

Comment: period column has type 'daterange' and own operators to find inclusion, length, intersection, etc and also there is an AND NOT EXISTS (...) subquery

Comment: ok. how can i call exec_query from model? and what should i put in binds?